# Save SVG File from wikipedia as SVG in python

Tags: python, selenium, svg, web-scraping, wikipedia

***Goal:***
save *SVG* from wikipedia

***Requirements:***
Needs to be automated

Currently I am using selenium to get some other information, and I tried to use a python script like this to extract the svg but the extracted ***SVG*** file gives an error when rendering.

Edit:
The same error occurs when using requests, maybe it has something to do with file wikipedia uploaded?

***Error code:***
[Errorcode for svg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpJsM.png)

It renders part of the svg later:
[Rendered part of SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC1Oy.png)

How it should look:
[Map;Oslo zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcYs5.png)

[Wikipedia file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/NO_0301_Oslo.svg)

Code *imageEctractSingle.py*:

```
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER_PATH = 'chromedriver.exe'
link = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/NO_0301_Oslo.svg'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get(link)
image = driver.page_source
#Creates an SVG File
f = open("kart/oslo.svg", "w")
f.write(image)
f.close()
driver.close()
```

[Original artical that I get the file link from by running through the table in the article](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norges_kommuner)

Any ideas on how to exctract this image, I know chrome as a built in function to save as, how can I access that through selenium?

or does there exsist a tool for saving SVG files from selenium?

Thanks in advance for any help :D

Comment: does it NEED to be in selenium?

Comment: No it doesn't. I am sorry I should write it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not selenium but I got it working in requests, you shouldn't need selenium for something this simple unless you are doing more alongside it:

```py
import requests


def write_text(data: str, path: str):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(data)


url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/NO_0301_Oslo.svg'

svg = requests.get(url).text

write_text(svg, './NO_0301_Oslo.svg')
```

Comment: Hei, I tried this but I still the same kind of error as before when I run the script. I thought yesterday that might be because of there being other elements in the svg on wikipedia, like 
     <script></script>

Comment: It works for me, maybe its an encoding thing or maybe you are using an svg viewer that doesn't support some of the features in the file. I opened the downloaded file in my browser and it renders fine.

Comment: I will take a deeper look into this, and try to figure out what goes wrong.
Thanks for the help :D